# Excel column comparing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on comparing markup values between three different databases. I have each database in a seperate colomn. What is the formula to see if all 6 markup values are the same. To get a Yes if they are and a no if they are not? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3):

Exact will return True if the cells are the same.

```
=EXACT(A1,B1)
```

[image]

or for multiple values: 1=true (same)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1=B1)*(B1=C1)*(C1=D1)*(D1=E1)*(E1=F1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it will only allow me to do two columns I have 6.

Comment: Try edited version